# python3.6 URLLIB Request

Tags: python-3.x, url, request

Eu tenho este código:

```
import urllib.request

x = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.google.com')
print (x.read())
```

E o erro que acontece :

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "python", line 3, in
>    urllib.error.URLError:

Parece que a urllib.request não tem mais a função `urlopen` ...

Alguém pode ajudar?

Answer (score -1):

Amigo,

Apesar de vc falar python3, vc esta usando o python2 na hora de executar o script!

Seu código funcionou perfeitamente no meu python3.6! Agora o procedimento muda um pouco caso utilize o python2, vc tem que usar o modulo: urllib2 e segue:

```
import urllib2
req = urllib2.Request('http://www.google.com')
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
pagina = response.read()
print(pagina)
```

Desta forma vc atinge o mesmo objetivo no python2.7! Veja se minha resposta atende.